# SignalR: puzzled by method names - CamelCase vs lowerCamelCase - what's the sense?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

Could you tell me why names in Hub-classes are in CamelCase, but in client-side js-code it's in lowerCamelCase? And why I can't call Hello-method from MyHub-class just by `MyHub.server.Hello`?

I mean it would be more clear to call the backend-methods be their exact c#-names, isn't it? Does that renaming have any other meaning apart from code-style agreements?

I hope my question is clear enough.

In script.js:

```
$(function() {
    var hub = $.connection.myHub;

    hub.client.hello = function (message) { //why not hub.client.Hello ?
        alert(message);
    }

    $("#btn").click(function(){
         hub.server.hello(); //why not hub.server.Hello() ??
    });

});
```

In MyHub-class:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public void Hello()
        {
            Clients.All.hello(); //why not Clients.All.Hello() ?
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is due to the naming convention and SignalR proxy codes.

JavaScript is a case-sensitive language where as Dotnet suggests CamelCasing.
Calling a method on the server side goes through the proxy codes which is in javascript.

Comment: Adding to what Rahatur posted. when we include <script src="signalr/hubs"></script> a file hubs.js is generated automatically by the signalr framework and this follows the convention (hub name / async methos are camel cased in javascript and pascal cased in c#) You also have a choice to not use this proxy. Simply do not include this line and create you own proxy. Then you can use exact names in both javascript and c# code.
also instead of hub.server you have to use hub.invoke('Hello'). If you think, using different casing can cause confusion, you can use later.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript conventionally uses the `camelCase` naming convention for method names, 
the .net ecosystem conventionally uses `PascalCase`. 
Javascript and some of the .net languages are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't agree with others saying that it should be camel case because javascript uses camel case, since SignalR is not restricted to javascript client, but you could also have e.g. .NET client which still uses pascal case.

That being said, I think this is totally up to you to define your naming conventions for method names to whatever feels natural to you.